# Material design input - bug in focus effect

Tags: css, material-design

I was looking for a good Material Design input tutorial - which I found [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/google-material-design-input-boxes-in-css3) -, but when I tried to apply this in my code, the underlines don't match up.
The underline when focused is shorter than the regular `border-bottom`.

Here's the live example of what I mean: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/PieterVDE/pen/LVQZaY?editors=110)

And here's the code:

```css
input {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 5px;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #757575;
}
.bar {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
}
.bar:before,
.bar:after {
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  width: 0;
  bottom: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(37, 116, 169, 0.50);
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
}
.bar:before {
  left: 50%;
}
.bar:after {
  right: 50%;
}
/* active state */

input:focus ~ .bar:before,
input:focus ~ .bar:after {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="group">
    <input type="text" required>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <label>Name</label>
  </div>

  <div class="group">
    <input type="text" required>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <label>Email</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Is there anyone who knows why this happens?

Comment: Just FYI, google released their own CSS library for that yesterday: http://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html#textfields-section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `box-sizing:border-box;` on the input elements:

```css
input {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 5px;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #757575;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  outline:none;
}
.bar {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
}
.bar:before,
.bar:after {
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  width: 0;
  bottom: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(37, 116, 169, 0.50);
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
}
.bar:before {
  left: 50%;
}
.bar:after {
  right: 50%;
}
/* active state */

input:focus ~ .bar:before,
input:focus ~ .bar:after {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="group">
    <input type="text" required>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <label>Name</label>
  </div>

  <div class="group">
    <input type="text" required>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <label>Email</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

That, or set the width of the spans to about 315px which should match the width of the inputs when you factor in the border and padding.

Comment: Wow, I seemed to have missed that one. Thanks!